# Using trained classifer file with weka

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka, svm

I am working on svmlight classifier for last few days. I have trained file, which is trained by svmlight classifier which is of 114MB size.

As I am not familiar with Weka, I want to know can I use this trained file with weka svm classifier?

Trained file format is like this:

```
SVM-light Version V6.02
0 # kernel type
3 # kernel parameter -d
1 # kernel parameter -g
1 # kernel parameter -s
1 # kernel parameter -r
empty# kernel parameter -u
696 # highest feature index
1249668 # number of training documents
127580 # number of support vectors plus 1
0 # threshold b, each following line is a SV (starting with alpha*y)
0.046276536531765000148652688949369 4:1 6:1 8:1 17:1 23:1 28:1 32:1 36:1 40:1 44:1 48:1 52:1 56:1 60:1 64:1 68:1 72:1 76:1 80:1 81:1 88:1 89:1 96:1 100:1 104:$
-0.011569134132941250037163172237342 4:1 6:1 8:1 17:1 23:1 28:1 32:1 36:1 40:1 44:1 48:1 52:1 56:1 60:1 64:1 68:1 69:1 76:1 80:1 84:1 88:1 89:1 96:1 100:1 101$
-0.011569134132941250037163172237342 4:1 6:1 8:1 17:1 23:1 28:1 32:1 36:1 40:1 44:1 48:1 52:1 56:1 60:1 64:1 68:1 72:1 76:1 80:1 81:1 88:1 89:1 96:1 100:1 104$
-0.011569134132941250037163172237342 4:1 6:1 8:1 17:1 23:1 28:1 32:1 36:1 40:1 44:1 48:1 52:1 56:1 60:1 64:1 68:1 72:1 76:1 80:1 81:1 88:1 89:1 96:1 100:1 104$
-0.011569134132941250037163172237342 4:1 6:1 8:1 17:1 23:1 28:1 #
0.046276536531765000148652688949369 5:1 6:1 16:1 18:1 26:1 28:1 32:1 36:1 40:1 44:1 48:1 52:1 56:1 60:1 64:1 68:1 72:1 76:1 80:1 82:1 86:1 89:1 96:1 100:1 104$
-0.011569134132941250037163172237342 5:1 6:1 16:1 18:1 26:1 28:1 32:1 36:1 40:1 44:1 48:1 52:1 56:1 60:1 64:1 68:1 72:1 73:1 80:1 84:1 88:1 89:1 96:1 100:1 10$
-0.011569134132941250037163172237342 5:1 6:1 16:1 18:1 26:1 28:1 32:1 36:1 40:1 44:1 48:1 52:1 56:1 60:1 64:1 68:1 72:1 76:1 80:1 84:1 85:1 89:1 96:1 100:1 10$
-0.011569134132941250037163172237342 5:1 6:1 16:1 18:1 26:1 28:1 32:1 36:1 40:1 44:1 48:1 52:1 56:1 60:1 64:1 68:1 72:1 76:1 80:1 84:1 85:1 89:1 96:1 100:1 10$
-0.011569134132941250037163172237342 5:1 6:1 16:1 18:1 26:1 28:1 #
0.19667528026000125063177392803482 1:1 6:1 8:1 17:1 26:1 28:1 32:1 36:1 40:1 43:1 46:1 52:1 56:1 60:1 64:1 68:1 72:1 76:1 80:1 84:1 88:1 89:1 96:1 100:1 103:1$
-0.011569134132941250037163172237342 1:1 6:1 8:1 17:1 26:1 28:1 32:1 36:1 40:1 44:1 45:1 52:1 56:1 60:1 64:1 68:1 72:1 76:1 80:1 84:1 88:1 89:1 96:1 100:1 104$
```

and so on, 127580 support vectors.

**Is it possible to use this trained file with weka or any other svm classifier?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to import the SVM Classifier Model from svmlight to Weka.  Unfortunately, I don't believe that this would be very easy to import (perhaps from code, but you would likely need to have both a knowledge of the svmlight and Weka implementations of the SVM model's file structure to translate).

You may need to retrain a new SVM from Weka if you intend to use its implementation.

I can't speak for other SVM Classifiers, but it may be the same situation if they are not compatible with the file structure outlined above.

Comment: thanks dear. ACtually I dont have the dataset which has been used with svmlight classifier. I have just trained file. So I just thought that it would be great if I can use this trained file with weka

Comment: No worries dearie!  Just to be sure, when you say 'trained file', you mean the model and not the training set, right?  If so, it would likely be difficult to transfer to another package.

Comment: @Mathew: Actually I dont know correct terminology. I thought trained file and model are same. The file is named is modelrank, and I believe it is trained using bunch of document so I called it as trained file